# MultiScaleTileSource and Collections

Tags: deepzoom, multiscaleimage

Does anyone know how to override the GetTileLayers for a collection in the MultiScaleTileSource class.    I want to set the source to a xml document ( which is a deep zoom collection doc ).  I need to remap where the images come from and the filename format.

This is simple with a single image, but how do you do it for a collection?

Anyone?

thanks
D

Answer (score 1):

It might not be officially possible.  Check out [this thread](http://getsatisfaction.com/livelabs/topics/custom_dz_source_for_collection).

A related question might be why the tileImageLayerSources argument of MultiScaleTileSource.GetTileLayers is not specifically a collection of Uris and why is it a collection... i.e. why would we want to add multiple Uris in one call?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do "dynamic" deep zoom is instead of setting the source for the MSI directly to the XML, set it to an ASPX handler that returns the xml you generate on the fly.  If you're not sure what I'm saying, let me know and I can reply with more detail.